# How do I ignore the first(or certain) lines when parsing a string/file in python?

Tags: python, html, parsing, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm working on a program that parses through different profiles on a website. All profiles have some text that is always there, and to grab these fields, I use the .index() object to slice them. However, these owners of these profiles may in a rare case use some of the key words from the actual html document in their "profile description". The text for the profile description is one of the first few lines of the html document. How do I make sure I skip the first few lines every time I parse the document?

example code:

```
from bs4 import BeatifulSoup
import urllib.request


country_id = 56451
country_url = "http://www.blocgame.com/stats.php?id=" + str(country_id)
country_source = urllib.request.urlopen(country_url)

country_page = BeautifulSoup(country_source, 'html.parser')
country_text = country_page.get_text()


#This is a game where each player owns their country in the cold war

#This checks for the airforce level
def check_airfoce_cosmetic():
    cforce_slice1 = int(country_text.index("Airforce:"))
    cforce_slice2 = int(country_text.index("Navy:"))
    country_airforce_cosmetic = country_text[cforce_slice1:cforce_slice2] 
    print(country_airforce_cosmetic + "\n\n")

#However, the player might have something in their description bragging about their airforce.
```

If this question is worded badly for you just let me know.

Comment: This is a web crawler? You are using selenium + phantomjs? You could post here the link page and your code?

Comment: I'm using beautiful soup alone, I'll put some examples of the code up in a second.

Comment: What is the tag for the profile description?

Comment: @dstudeba http://pastebin.com/w7nRV7JP

Comment: What is `country_text` and what is your expected output?

Comment: @dstudeba I've added it. It gets all the raw text out of the html file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use the index, you can pull the text as a string out and then parse the string.  Not the most elegant, but works.

```
country_id = 56451
country_url = "http://www.blocgame.com/stats.php?id=" + str(country_id)
country_source = urllib.request.urlopen(country_url)

country_page = BeautifulSoup(country_source)
country_text = country_page.text
rawAirforce = country_text.split("Airforce:")[1]
navyArray = rawAirforce.split("Navy:")
airforce = navyArray[0].strip()
navy = navyArray[1].split("Chemical Weapons:")[0].strip()
print("Airforce: " + airforce + " Navy: " + navy)
```

Produces

```
Airforce: Very Powerful Navy: Coast Guard
        22 ships
```

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten around a problem like this by using bs4's decompose to remove the potentially dangerous part of the HTML. For example for a page_html soup looking like this:

`<about>Not important, and possibly dangerous!</about>
<stats>This is the important part.</stats>`

i'd do something like:

`not_needed = page_html.about
not_needed.decompose()`

Then you're left with just `<stats>This is the important part.</stats>`. So you could just remove the User's personal description entirely and then safely extract whatever you need.